# can i show indent grid in Notepad ++?

Tags: html, css, notepad++

i am using notepad++ and Visual studio to edit LESS css file. both work fine. but i am unable to check open and close brace in it.

visual studio show me indent using a plugin in visual studio but i need same thing in notepad++.

are this possible to get using any plugin in notepad ++

thanks

Comment: While you're asking, if someone knows a similar plugin for Dreamweaver I'd love to know.

Comment: This question might be better suited at [superuser](http://superuser.com/) forum, which is more application oriented.

Comment: @Mattias Alfborger: [nope](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions)

Comment: Please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999